# truncated decimal point number inserted incorrect into mssql

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I have width and height in centimeter and i calculate the area like this :

```
 var res = ((width * height) / 10000);
```

(divided  10000 to make it as meter)

the problem is :

I want to insert the result into microsoft sqlserver table and i truncate the point part of number into 2 digit :

```
 res = Math.Truncate(res *  100) /  100;
```

Then i insert it into table,if i input two number like 216 and 152 the result will be 3.28,
till here everything is ok but,when i check the result in database i see this : 
**3.280000002**
I truncate it in my store procedure like this :

```
 Round(Area,2)
```

But it did not solve my problem.

Comment: Hi,you needs to store only 2 decimal places in DB. right?

Comment: yes (216*152)/10000=3.2832 but i want 3.28

Comment: then why cant you change the DB feild decimal places to 2.then u can get that result

Comment: so give me a solution,what can i do?

Comment: can u change the DB column size to - decimal(xx, 2). and try

Comment: I recommend you read up on floating point numbers and the implications. E.g. [here](http://floating-point-gui.de/) and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)